# How to change default linter for a project in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, lint, babeljs

I am using Sublime Text 3, and I have installed [`babel-sublime`](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) using Package Control.

I would now like to use `babel-sublime` as my linter for all JS files in a project, but *not* as my default linter for all JS files. Currently my project seems to be using `jshint`, probably because that's set in my overall Sublime settings.

How can I do this? The [babel-sublime documentation](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) explains how to set it as the default linter for all `.js` files, but that's not what I want - I just want to use it for this one project.